# method works but returns not found error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I requested method and see how it runs but get 404 error

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUser(@RequestHeader(value="Access-key") String accessKey,
                    @RequestHeader(value="Secret-key") String secretKey){
        User u = this.userService.chkCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        System.out.println(u.toString());
        return u;
}
```

I can see results in `System.out.print()` and then something happens and return statement don't returns object.

The stack trace is,

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found
>   for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/user.jsp] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'.

But all other methods convert object into JSON and returns it

Comment: Please provide at least a portion of your stack trace.

Comment: Do you have a mapping for `views/user.jsp` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I haven't any jsp object but other methods returns json without any additional settings

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the method is to point a **view**. The error message indicates that the controller cannot find view corresponding the User object. Documentation here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: But I don't need pointing to view I want get json and other methods returns it

Comment: I found this example. Can you try ResponseBody annotation? http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Comment: now I got 500 error, and System.out.print() still working

Comment: Can you check jackson library in classpath?

Comment: yes, Jackson is there

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: No, there is no messages. println and then [28/07/2015:02:27:22 +0000] "GET /user HTTP/1.1" 500

Comment: I see. How about messages in the web browser?

Comment: no, the same situation

Comment: Then it's better to focus on changing your web server's debug level or verbosity. As other folks say, having stack trace is helpful to troubleshoot many issues. (The methology is beyond this topic)